# Some questions concerning dimension of $Hom$ space and number of composition factors

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

These two questions are taking from Jon Alperin's 'Local Representation Theory' question 2 from page 37, 53 respectively.

1). Let $S$ be an $A$-module with corresponding projective module $P$, then the multiplicity of $S$ as a composition factor of the $A$-module $U= dim$ $Hom_A (P,U)$.

2).If $S$ is a simple $kG$-module then the multiplicity of $S$ as a composition factor of $U/rad(U)$, for a $kG$-module $U$ $=dim$ $Hom_{kG} (U,S)$.

I just don't have much tools when it comes to composition factors.

Also on page 119, fourth line from the bottom, he says that 'if S is a simple $A$-module and $P_S$ is the corresponding indecomposable projective module, then $rad(P_S)/soc(P_S)$ is the direct sum of two uniserial modules (can be zero)'. Why is this true?

Comment: OK, 2) looks simple now, the quotient is semisimple then we reduce it to the projective case then it is easy.